# Can you write pure JavaScript expressions in Kendo MVVM views (as with Knockout)?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, kendo-ui

In the following, isDirty returns a boolean, depending on whether the user has changed any of the observable properties.

HTML

```
<div class="status-message" data-bind="text:isDirty ? user.nickName : user.suffix>
```

JS

```
viewModel = new kendo.observable({
   user: {
   emailAddress: user.emailAddress,
   firstName: user.firstName,
   middleInitial: user.middleInitial,
   lastName: user.lastName,
   title: user.title,
   suffix: user.suffix,
   nickName: user.nickName
}
});
```

I've done it with Knockout, but for some reason I can't get this to work with Kendo's MVVM.

Is this just a limitation of Kendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use JS in `data-bind`, but there are other ways to achieve what you want to do.
One way would be to create two status-message divs and use the `visible` binding on both.
Another way would be to use a method to get the data to display.

HTML:

```
<div id="bindme">
    <!-- alternative #1 -->
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: user.emailAddress" />
    <div data-bind="visible: isDirty">
        <div class="status-message" data-bind="text: user.nickName"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="invisible: isDirty">
        <div class="status-message" data-bind="text: user.suffix"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- alternative #2 -->
    <div class="status-message" data-bind="text: currentValue"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
viewModel = new kendo.observable({
    isDirty: false,
    user: {
        emailAddress: "a",
        firstName: "b",
        middleInitial: "c",
        lastName: "d",
        title: "e",
        suffix: "f",
        nickName: "g"
    },
    currentValue: function () {
        return this.get("isDirty") ? this.get("user.nickName") : this.get("user.suffix")
    }
});

viewModel.bind("change", function () {
    this.set("isDirty", true);
});

kendo.bind($("#bindme"), viewModel);
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/dE2hz/))